# C Programming: Preprocessor, include files from macro

Tags: c, macros, include, c-preprocessor

If I could find a way to do something similar to this, I could cut out hundreds of lines of code in my application, and dramatically increase maintainability. Anyone have any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( )
{
  #define include_all_files(root)   \
            #include #root "1.h"    \
            #include #root "2.h"    \
            #include #root "3.h"    \
            #include #root "4.h"

  include_all_files( first_library )
  include_all_files( second_library )
  include_all_files( third_library )

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:

I appreciate the responses, my example seems to be causing a misdirection in effort, so here is the problem I am actually trying to solve:

I am implementing a finite state machine. Through naming conventions, I have gotten it to be as simple to add a state as:

```
  STATE(initial_screen)
    #include "initial_screen.state"
  END_STATE

  STATE(login)
    #include "login.state"
  END_STATE
```

However, if I could answer the original question, I could refactor this down to something as simple as:

```
  ADD_STATE(initial_screen)
  ADD_STATE(login)
```

This is because the file name and the state name, and all the underlying wiring and everything else all follow similar conventions. However, I cannot figure out how to implement the include file based on the token received in a macro.

Comment: probably better to edit your first post instead of adding comments to it.

Comment: Thank you, Anders, I didn't realize I could do that, I have added the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is beyond the capabilities of the C preprocessor.

Have you considered using something like [m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) instead?

Comment: Thank you, LnxPrgr3, I'll have to read the docs to see if it is compatible with my school computers, but this is the kind of thing I have been desiring for a while, I think ^^

Comment: Lol, it is already installed on my school computers ^_^ Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 7):

Why not just create a header file that itself `#include`s all of the other header files for the library? Then for each library you'd just include that library's one meta-header.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your clarified problem, you could just refactor `initial_screen.state` and `login.state` so that they start with `STATE()` and end with `END_STATE`.  Then you can just do:

```
#include "initial_screen.state"
#include "login.state"
```

...which is equivalent to what you're after - it's just an `#include` instead of an `ADD_STATE`.

Answer (score 1):

In file includes.h

```
#include "1.h"
#include "2.h"
#include "3.h"
```

In all other files

```
#include "includes.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

The #include pre-process directive being itself handled at in the same step as the macro evaluation, this would likely not work.  I don't believe the pre-processing can be recursive. (or iterative, for that matter).

Instead, **the typical way this is done** is to create a small include file which includes all the desired #includes.  See Cory Petosky's reponse for an illustration.

**A word of caution**:
While this may cut hundreds of line of code, you should consider that **these are "easy" lines of code**.  One typically skims over them, unlike lines of codes associated with the true logic of the program.

Furthermore, explicitly listing the individual includes necessary for a given file provide a bit of self documentation, and make it easier for refactoring the code when needed.

**Edit**: This just in ;-)
Someone just asked this SO question [**Good idea to put all project headers into one file?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768075/is-it-a-good-idea-to-put-all-project-headers-into-one-file-headers-h), and the responses seem to generally agree with my take that there's typically little gain to be had from grouping headers.